# Add default value to select with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, angular

I'm developing an Angular 2 app with ASP.NET Core 2.0 using the Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Angular Web application template.

I have a controller whose method get returns all the legislations that I'm using in my app (they come from an Enum):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class LawController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Models.LawPresentation> Get()
    {
        List<LawPresentation> laws = new List<LawPresentation>();
        // Arrange
        byte[] values = (byte[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(LawTypes));
        foreach (byte value in values)
        {
            string enumName = Enum.GetName(typeof(LawTypes), value);
            LawPresentation law = new LawPresentation()
            {
                Value = value,
                Name = enumName
            };

            laws.Add(law);
        }

        return laws;
    }
}
```

I this is the component that shows all these values in a select:

```
<p *ngIf="!laws"><em>Loading...</em></p>
Legislaciones:&nbsp;
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let l of laws" [ngValue]="l">{{l.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I don't think that return the default value (a blank option) from the controller is a good idea, so I wondering if I can add something to the html component to add the default option.

Is there any way to add the default option to the select into the html component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<p *ngIf="!laws"><em>Loading...</em></p>
Legislaciones:&nbsp;
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option *ngFor="let l of laws" [ngValue]="l">{{l.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a default option as below.
selected property will make option selected at initial.
disable property will restrict option to be selected by user.
You can remove them as per requirement

```
<p *ngIf="!laws"><em>Loading...</em></p>
Legislaciones:&nbsp;
<select>
    <option value="" selected disabled>SELECT</option>
    <option *ngFor="let l of laws" [ngValue]="l">{{l.name}}</option>
</select>
```